# Do I need to add a protective layer to insulation for wall heater?

Tags: insulation, walls, heater

I am going to install a 4000 watt wall heater to an add on. It is the kind of wall heater that is seated in the wall. i also plan to install insulation in between my wall studs. there will be insulation above and below the wall heater. Is insulation flammable? and will/Should I put something on the two ends of insulation? some kind of foil or something?

Also just a quick question its a 240 volt heater. I have bought 10/2 wire for it. will that work? and what kind of breaker should i use?

Comment: What kind of insulation? The installation instructions should have specific requirements for clearance to combustibles, and breaker size. The wire size depends on the length of the run, #10 should be plenty though. Are you sure the heater doesn't use a neutral connection, requiring 3 conductors?

Comment: Roll insulation. the instructions don't say anything about insulation or breaker size. and 10/2 has a neutral doesnt it? a hot, neutral, and ground?

Comment: @Kevin 10/2 w/ground has 2 insulated conductors, and one bare conductor.  To get 240V you'll need two ungrounded (hot) conductors (one from each leg of the panel), so you won't have a grounded conductor (neutral) in the cable. Since it sounds like you're not very familiar with electrical work, it might be best if you contacted a qualified Electrician to install the heater. Also, it might be better if you ask a separate question to deal with the electrical stuff.

Comment: By "roll insulation" do you mean fiberglass?

Comment: and does it have a kraft paper facing? If so, where is it in relationship to the heater? The instructions wouldn't refer to insulation, but to combustible materials.

Comment: Where are you located? And where did you purchase this heater from? If the heater is certified by something like UL then it will list things like clearances, etc. If it's not certified, I wouldn't trust it to not burn down my house.

Comment: Make and Model? Usually the manuals are available online anymore and will have specific installation instructions. Fireblock in the wall above the heater installation bay will be needed. Kraft paper moisture barrier used on fiberglass insulation is highly flammable and often uses tar to adhere the fiberglass to it and would be a bad idea anywhere near a heat source.